# Python to transform street type abbreviation?

Tags: python, street-address

I am dealing with addresses matching such as `123 Main St. Suite 100 Chicago, IL` and `123 Main Street Chicago, IL`. One important problem is to transform abbreviations of street type, such as `St.` to `Street`. I wonder if there is any Python package that deals with it since it seems like a very common problem for dealing with addresses.

PS, I know [usaddress](http://usaddress.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#), but it only parses out all the parts, does not do any transformation.

Comment: http://bcdcspatial.blogspot.com/2012/09/normalize-to-usps-street-abbreviations.html

Comment: You can probably make a simple dictionary out of the allowed abbreviations and if you are really ambitious, submit it to `usaddress`.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert to an abbreviation followed by a period by using address and usaddress. I used usaddress since I know it will parse addresses such as 123 S North Dr. This is part of what I did:

```
import usaddress
from address import AddressParser, Address
addr = usaddress.parse(address_line1)
ad = AddressParser()
addr2 = ad.parse_address(address_line1)
#perform some cleanup and functions on addr...
if addr2.street_suffix:
    post = addr2.street_suffix
else:
    post = ''
```

[Here is the documentation on the address 0.1.1 module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/address/0.1.1).

Update: address does not work in Python 3.x because there is a print function without (). There is another module, street-address [documentation here](https://pypi.org/project/street-address/) that works similarly for formatting and parsing addresses, but I've found usaddress is sufficient.

For example,

```
    parser_address = "6400 S FIDDLERS GREEN CIR SUIT 123"
    addr = usaddress.parse(parser_address)
```

returns:

```
     [('6400', 'AddressNumber'), ('S', 'StreetNamePreDirectional'), ('FIDDLERS', 'StreetName'), ('GREEN', 'StreetName'), ('CIR', 'StreetNamePostType'), ('SUIT', 'OccupancyType'), ('123', 'OccupancyIdentifier')]
```